# how to place value of xpath in to html img tag

Tags: xml, xslt

The following code gets me the appropriate string, but I don't know how to put the value in to an html img tag:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MT[@N = 'tag']/@V" />
```

I've tried this:

```
<img src="<xsl:value-of select="MT[@N = 'tag']/@V" />
```

and several variations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an Attribute Value Template ([AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates))

```
<img src="{MT[@N = 'tag']/@V}" />
```